# Linq to sql and timestamp field

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, timestamp

I've created table with timestamp field. *Allow Nulls* property is set to *false*.
When I want to update *entity* from *repository*, I get *null* value for that field, but in databse this field is set to some value.
Does anyone knows what may be the problem?
I get the correct values for other fields.
Thank you.

**edit**:
When I get *entity* from the *repository*, timestamp field is set appropriately.
Problem is somewhere in `http post`:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Product product)
```

The value of timestamp field is lost here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Edit view that VS generates excludes binary fields. To include a Timestamp field in the view, you'll have to add to your view a hidden field like this one:

```
<%: Html.Hidden("Timestamp", Model.Timestamp.ToString()) %>
```

You'll also have to add this line to your Web.config if you get a compilation error like I did (using VS 2010):

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

because Timestamp.ToString() is an extension method.

Keep in mind that you cannot explicitly change a timestamp field in the database. SQL Server manages that.